# How do I reduce the output in a stack trace?

Tags: ruby

Is there any way to reduce the amount of output provided by Ruby when there's an error?

For example:

```
rspec bowling_spec.rb 
/Users/snowcrash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require': cannot load such file -- bowling (LoadError)
  from /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:45:in `require'
  from /Users/snowcrash/Developer/Code/Ruby/RSpec/bowling_spec.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  from /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rspec-core-2.14.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load'
  from /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rspec-core-2.14.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `block in load_spec_files'
  from /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rspec-core-2.14.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `each'
  from /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rspec-core-2.14.2/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:896:in `load_spec_files'
  from /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rspec-core-2.14.2/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
  from /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rspec-core-2.14.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:80:in `run'
  from /Users/snowcrash/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/gems/rspec-core-2.14.2/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

All I'm interested in is the first line, `cannot load such file -- bowling (LoadError)`. Ideally I'd like Ruby to not spit out the rest of the `from` lines.

Is this possible?

Comment: ... Why? More info is good, and you're not forced to read it. Someday you'll encounter an error where you really *do* want a stack trace.

Comment: It takes up valuable screen space and makes it harder to read the actual error. And the day I really do want a stack trace I'd run a switch to call it up.

Answer (score 2):

Do something like this:

```
module Kernel
  at_exit do
    case $!
    when nil, SystemExit, Interrupt
    else puts $!.message, $@.first
    end
    $stderr.reopen(IO::NULL)
    $stdout.reopen(IO::NULL)
  end
end
```

Comment: Better than loading an entire library for one feature!

Comment: Might be being a bit dense here but how would I use that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Unix/Linux OS, and you're running tests from the command line, you can do

```
rspec bowling_spec.rb | head -n 20
```

to ensure you don't have to scroll up to see your error.